# Extract author of a newspaper article (regex problem)

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to extract the author of newspaper articles like those two in VB.Net (I thought I could use regular expressions, but I didn't found a reliable way to do it):

1. https://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/kein-brexit-chaos-an-grenze-zwischen-frankreich-und-grossbritannien-17130243.html
2. https://www.nytimes.com/2021/01/04/world/europe/assange-extradition-denied.html

Until now, I tried this (for article 1):

```
Dim x As New WebClient()
Dim source As String = x.DownloadString("https://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/kein-brexit-chaos-an-grenze-zwischen-frankreich-und-grossbritannien-17130243.html")
Dim pattern1 As String = Chr(34) & "author" & ":" & Chr(34) & "(.*)" & Chr(34) & ","
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(source, pattern1)
MsgBox(m.Groups(0).ToString)
```

The Mesagebox should display the name Philip Plickert, but it returns nothing.

Does someone can give me a hint or code how I can do it (I'm very new to regular expressions)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern instead:

`/<a class=\"atc-MetaAuthorLink\" href=".+">(.+)<\/font>/g`

Play with it here:

https://regex101.com/r/GDOBLq/1